# Custom Button OnClick event

Tags: delphi, onclick, delphi-xe7

I create buttons at runtime and would like to be able to set custom OnClick event that each button would pass it's own custom values when clicked:

I get error when trying to assiign custom OnClick procedure:

```
E2010 Incompatible types: 'TNotifyEvent' and 'procedure, untyped pointer or untyped parameter'
```

here is how i use it:

```
procedure myOnClick(Sender:TObject; Info1:string; info2:integer);
begin
  // process info1, info2 based on which button is Sender
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var vBtn:Tbutton;
  Idx:integer;
  vStr:string;
begin
   // ...

   // create btn
   vBtn := Tbutton.Create(nil);
   vBtn.Parent := Form1.ButtonsPanel;
   vBtn.Tag := Idx;
   vBtn.OnClick:=myOnCLick(self,vStr,vBtn.Tag);

   // assign btn
   //...

end;
```

**How can I use custom click event, procedure, so I can pass values specific to the button, when button is clicked?**

---

**EDIT:**

right now I use the CustomOnClick:

```
procedure TForm1.CustomOnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  myOnClick(Sender,TControl(Sender).Tag);
end;

vBtn.OnClick:=Form1.CustomOnClick; // works, but only accepts Sender parameter
```

As David suggested, I already use Tag property. Now I need more info and would like to get rid of this 'middle man' CustomOnClick and call myOnClick directly.

Comment: You don't get to make up the signature of the events. They are handed down to you, written in stone. Use something like `Tag` to hold button specific information. Put a pointer to a record in there. Or a reference to a class instance. Or subclass from TButton and put the information in there as a field. That latter approach is by some distance to be preferred.

Comment: Or create an array of the vStr values, and use .`Tag` as an index to the array. If you want more information, use an array of record, or object list etc

Comment: Tag can hold a pointer so you can put any information you like in there.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I guess you're right, can't change default events. I thought some concepts from Generics would apply and allow easier event overloading or extending.

Comment: The component raises the event. And the component author has already determined what parameters to pass. You cannot expect the component to pass parameters that are not known to it. If events were anon methods, then you could use variable capture to capture state. But they are not anon methods. There are no generics here.

Comment: Aha, anonymous, generics - not the same, it's all part of 'new dev features' which I'm slowly getting to know. Now I understand why overloading like in my example is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1**

You can store "button info" separatelly, like there:

```
type
  TButtonInfo = record
    info1: string;
    info2: Integer;
    info3: Double;

    constructor Create(const AInfo1: string; AInfo2: integer; AInfo3: Double);
  end;

  TButtonInfoDictionary = class(TDictionary<TObject,TButtonInfo>)
  end;

  TForm6 = class(TForm)
  .....
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FButtonInfoDict: TButtonInfoDictionary;
    procedure OnButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
  public
    { Public declarations }
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

implementation

constructor TButtonInfo.Create(const AInfo1: string; AInfo2: integer;
  AInfo3: Double);
begin
  Info1:=AInfo1;
  Info2:=AInfo2;
  Info3:=AInfo3;
end;

procedure TForm6.btnAddNewButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  btn: TButton;
begin
  if not Assigned(FButtonInfoDict) then
    FButtonInfoDict:=TButtonInfoDictionary.Create;

  btn:=TButton.Create(nil);
  btn.Parent:=Self;
  btn.Align:=alTop;
  btn.Caption:='btn'+FButtonInfoDict.Count.ToString;
  btn.OnClick:=OnButtonClick;

  FButtonInfoDict.Add(btn, TButtonInfo.Create(FButtonInfoDict.Count.ToString, FButtonInfoDict.Count, 0));
end;

destructor TForm6.Destroy;
begin
  FreeAndNil(FButtonInfoDict);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TForm6.OnButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ButtonInfo: TButtonInfo;
begin
  if Assigned(FButtonInfoDict) then
    if FButtonInfoDict.TryGetValue(Sender, ButtonInfo) then
      Caption:=ButtonInfo.Info1+'  ' + ButtonInfo.info2.ToString;
end;
```

**Method 2** As David said, more preferred.

"Expand" TButton class and add needed properties to new class:

```
type
  TButton = class(Vcl.StdCtrls.TButton)
  private
    FInfo2: integer;
    FInfo1: string;
  public
    property Info1: string read FInfo1 write FInfo1;
    property Info2: integer read FInfo2 write FInfo2;
  end;

  TForm6 = class(TForm)
  .....
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure OnButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

procedure TForm6.btnAddNewButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  btn: TButton;
begin
  btn:=TButton.Create(nil);
  btn.Parent:=Self;
  btn.Align:=alTop;
  btn.Caption:='btn'+Self.Tag.ToString;
  btn.Info1:=Self.Tag.ToString;
  btn.Info2:=Self.Tag;
  btn.OnClick:=OnButtonClick;

  Self.Tag:=Self.Tag + 1;
end;

procedure TForm6.OnButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Sender is TButton then
    Caption:=TButton(Sender).Info1+'  ' + TButton(Sender).info2.ToString;
end;
```

**Method 3**, unwanted

Use dynamic allocated memory for store TButtonInfo from Method 1:

```
PButtonInfo = ^TButtonInfo;

procedure TForm6.btnAddNewButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  btn: TButton;
  pInfo: PButtonInfo;
begin
  btn:=TButton.Create(nil);
  btn.Parent:=Self;
  btn.Align:=alTop;
  btn.Caption:='btn'+Self.Tag.ToString;
  btn.OnClick:=OnButtonClick;

  New(pInfo); // once we have allocated memory, we need to release it after all.
  // but we dont have event, where we can call Dispose(PButtonInfo(btn.tag));
  // so, we have memory leak...
  // You can change TButtonInfo declaration from record to class,
  // and use .Create against New, but memory leak still there
  pInfo.info1:=Self.Tag.ToString;
  pInfo.info2:=Self.Tag;
  btn.Tag:=NativeInt(pInfo);

  Self.Tag:=Self.Tag + 1;
end;

procedure TForm6.OnButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Sender is TButton then
    Caption:=PButtonInfo(TButton(Sender).Tag).Info1+'  ' + PButtonInfo(TButton(Sender).Tag).info2.ToString;
end;
```

Comment: Great! I think Method 2 would fit best to implement with my code, let me see.

Comment: Can the `OnButtonClick` be defined differently and not in TForm (example #2)? I would like to keep as much as I can in separate unit for these button - without form. Is this possible?

Comment: @MikeTorrettinni, yes. But only as method in any object of any class, not as regular procedure. You can do `btn.OnClick:=myNewObjectOfSuperClass.ButtonClick`

Comment: @MikeTorrettinni  If you do this, you should relocate new TButton declaration to separate unit and include it into uses section in both Form unit and "another" unit. In Form unit this module must be after VCL.StdCtrls.

Comment: I managed to get it working in another unit, with dummy form  `FormX:TForm6;` - I assume not possible to do this without the dummy form, right?

Comment: @MikeTorrettinni  No. You can use **any** class and declare event handler in it. it doesn't have to be a form. But i guess, that you use auto-created forms only. You should create instance of object with event handler explicitly.

Comment: Excellent! I changed from Form to  `TDummyPlaceHolder = class(TObject); ...` and it works. This is better than Form class as is more clear what is used for - with some comments.